# PHP считается ли sleep() как время выполнения скрипта? ignore_user_abort(true); при закрытии сайта

Tags: php

Хотелось бы уточнить 2 вопроса. Есть скрипт, который должен выполнятся в течении нескольких минут, если быть конкретным, то 3. А именно идёт sleep(на три минуты), после чего выполняется код.

Так вот первое, на моей машине стоят стандартные значения настроек, что говорит о максимальном выполнении скрипта в 30 секунд. Следовательно появляется вопрос, стоит ли изменять параметр set_time_limit() на 3-4 минуты, для этого скрипта, или же sleep() не потребляет этого времени.

Второе, если я отправил ajax запрос на выполнение скрипта о котором идет речь, и до того как пройдет 3 минуты, я закрою вкладку, будет ли выполнен его конечный результат (внесение данных в бд)?   Или мне нужно указать параметр  ignore_user_abort(true);?

Comment: Вы собираетесь использовать sleep() только один раз ? или после каждого выполнения кода идёт sleep() ?

Comment: да, потребляет. Да, надо игнорировать

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от платформы. [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) под `windows` учитывает реальное время, на других платформах - время выполнения только PHP кода интерпретатором, в этом случае `sleep` не входит в это время.

```
melkij@melkij:~$ php -f test.php 
18:02:27
18:02:37
melkij@melkij:~$ cat test.php 
<?php 
echo date('H:i:s'),PHP_EOL;
set_time_limit(5);
sleep(10);
echo date('H:i:s'),PHP_EOL;
```

---

Поддержу озвученную мысль, что не стоит делать отложенное действие непосредственно в потоке веб-запроса. Хорошее решение заключается в фиксировании запроса в какой-либо очереди и отдельном (одном или нескольких) серверных процессов, которые эту очередь будут обрабатывать. Это позволит не мучаться вопросами, будет ли действие выполнено.

Answer (score 1):

Да время sleep() учитывается в общем времени выполнения скрипта.

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/995e0f3941d7a8c1c9e4b13bcea80890193f5811

Код теста:

```
$t1 = microtime(true);
sleep(1);
$t2 = microtime(true);

echo $t2-$t1; // 1.0001399517059
```

Да, но set_time_limit() скорее всего не сработает, придётся менять max_execution_time в php.ini

Да ignore_user_abort(true) лучше указать.

Но при накоплении большого количества спящих скриптов (начиная от 200) апач может упасть и тогда ни один не выполнится из тех, что висели в этот момент. Я бы задействовал очереди на БД - так надёжнее.

Comment: Спасибо, но не счет sleep так и не понял, автор ответа выше утверждает что на linux (у меня centos) sleep() не расходует время выполнения скрипта

Comment: @Владимир тест очень простой http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/995e0f3941d7a8c1c9e4b13bcea80890193f5811

Comment: А что вы таким тестом хотели проверить вообще? Что sleep задержит выполнение скрипта на секунду? Так для этого этот системный вызов и экспортирован.

Comment: @Мелкий смысл в том, что если в php.ini стоит max_execution_time = 30 а в скрипте sleep(29) то на работу у скрипта останется секунда. Таким образом, время проведённое в sleep учитывается во времени выполнения скрипта

Comment: И где в вашем тесте sleep(29) при max_execution_time = 30 и ещё секунда работы кода?

Comment: @Мелкий это другой пример песочница не даст столько времени )

Comment: Потому я и спрашиваю, что вы хотели этим тестом продемонстрировать. sleep работает как должен. Никакой взаимосвязи с max_execution_time (что то же самое что и set_time_limit) тест не показывает.

Comment: @Мелкий ладно, давайте так: в моём ответе есть ошибка? Если да, то в чём она заключается?

Comment: Скорее терминологическая путаница. sleep, разумеется, увеличивает общее время работы скрипта, для этого он и существует. Влияет ли sleep на таймер прерывания скрипта execution time limit - зависит от платформы.

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо, вас понял

Answer (score 0):

Время sleep() НЕ учитывается в общем времени выполнения скрипта.

Для своего конкретного случая простой тест...

```
$start = microtime(true);

echo "Начало работы скрипта<br><br>";

sleep(35);

echo "Проснулся...<br><br>";

echo "Время выполнения скрипта: ".round((microtime(true) - $start), 5)." сек.";
```

Т.е. на ограничение по умолчанию в 30сек. sleep() не влияет!